# On variant of integer factorization

Tags: computational-complexity, factorization

In the [post on site cstheory.stackexchange](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/4769/an-np-complete-variant-of-factoring?rq=1) on whether a variant of integer factorization
$$\mathsf{}\mbox{ }{\Pi} = \{\langle a, b, n \rangle \;|\; \exists \mbox{ } \mathsf{ an}\mbox{ }\mathsf{ integer}\mbox{ } m \in \{a, \ldots, b\}\mbox{ }\mathsf{ such}\mbox{ }\mathsf{that}\mbox{ }m | n\}$$
 is $\mathsf{NP}$ complete, it is clear that difference $b-a$ can neither be too small nor too big for the problem to remain $\mathsf{NP}$ complete under Cramér's conjecture.

What is the possible range of difference $b-a$ under which the problem remains $\mathsf{NP}$ complete under Cramér's conjecture?

Note in this problem $m$ need not be prime which makes the problem combinatorial rather than arithmetical

Comment: I don't understand - it is not even known that factorization is NP-complete.

Comment: This is a variant of factorization $m$ need not be prime.

Comment: @IgorRivin Check out answer and comments in link included in post

Comment: Factorization is factorization. It's still arithmetical, not combinatorial.

Comment: no this is not arithmetical at all, you can factorize into primes which are small but $m$ needs to be pieced together (this last step is not at all arithmetical) into a factor which is exponential in compared to any of prime factors

Comment: @IgorRivin The problem is that the number of divisors may be exponential. I believe one can assume the factorization of $n$ is given.

Comment: @joro Ah, I see...